# (XPages)How can change the banner color?

Tags: xpages, background-color, banner

I have an XPages, like this :

[image]

How can I change the banner color?

---

**2020/10/19 Update**

The following is the main design code, where can I change the banner color?

There is only "invertedNavbar"...

```
<xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <xp:callback facetName="facet_1" id="callback1"></xp:callback>
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xe:navigator id="navigator1" xp:key="LeftColumn"></xe:navigator>
        </xp:this.facets>
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration productLogoAlt="XPAGES" 
            titleBar="false" placeBar="false" footer="false" legal="false" invertedNavbar="true">
                <xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode label="HOME"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode label="INFO"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                    <xe:basicLeafNode label="PRODUCT"></xe:basicLeafNode>
                </xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>
            </xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
        </xe:this.configuration>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it can be modified through the css or theme definition of the XPage.
If you inspect the Element with the Developer Console in the Browser (F12 to open in most browsers) you should find out wich class is associated with the Element and should be modified.

Comment: When I inspect the element with the developer console in the browser, the code in the browser is different from the code of XPage.So, I don't know where should I modified.

Comment: If you can determine the style class of the generated header through the developer console you can search for that in the css files.
The Elements Tab in the developer console will also show you from which file the style definitions are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you can add your own CSS-class name to an element. Then create a stylesheet in your Design and define the class.